# Unity Instantiate bug

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I’ve created a script that should spawn enemies in some time, and it works perfectly. However, for some reason it shows errors, even then it spawns enemies like it should.

**Code:**

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] meteors;

    public GameObject meteor1;

    private float TimeBetweenSpawns;
    public float StartTimeBetweenSpawn = 1f;

    public float MaxY = 4.0f;
    public float MinY = -4.0f;
    float yPos;
    

    float MinTime = 1f;
    float MaxTime = 5f;

    private Vector3 spawnPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //ChangeSpawnTimes();

        

        yPos = Random.Range(MinY, MaxY);
        spawnPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, yPos, transform.position.z);


        int WhichMeteor = 0;
        int WhichMeteorRandom = Random.Range(1, 10);
        if(WhichMeteorRandom > 8)
        {
            WhichMeteor = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            WhichMeteor = 1;
        }
        Debug.Log(WhichMeteor.ToString());
        if (TimeBetweenSpawns <= 0)
        {
            Instantiate(meteors[0], transform.position, transform.rotation);

            //float Time = Random.Range(1f,5f);

            TimeBetweenSpawns = 1f;
        }
        else
        {
            TimeBetweenSpawns -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    private void ChangeSpawnTimes()
    {
        
        Debug.Log(Points.points);
    }
}
```

[Error out of bound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5La8T.png)

If I try to add only 1 metor not an array, just creating `GameObject` adding prefab to an inspector it again shows an error, but works as it should, i.e. it spawns enemies in a timely manner.

```
Instantiate(meteor1, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Found the mistake, added script twice to the object and only added values to one of them

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have an array in your code & you're trying to access one of its indexes that don't exist.

for example:

```
int[] r;
r[0] = 5
r[1] = 4;

// Error Happens Here
print(r[2]);
```

The error is because `r[2]` is null & isn't defined. So the solution is to check if the index is not null before trying to access it.